# How to obtain Block number of transaction?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core-development

Is there any function in `bitcoind` which when given the transaction(`CTransaction& tx`)/ transaction hash, returns its block number ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out what block a transaction is in?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37899/how-do-i-find-out-what-block-a-transaction-is-in)